# Not adding the class model to the list of models

Tags: flutter, list, dart, class, syntax

I fill a list through the text field and add that list to list 2 by a model, provided that none of the items of the first list are available in the models of the second list.
The problem is that in the first instance, the list is created and placed in the second list by a model, but if I want to put another list in the second list by the model, all the parameters of the list of models in the second list are changed to the current added value.

example :

step 1 : befor add item2 in the lis2 (item [1,2])
---print list 2--- > [{nameMarket: name, listCodeMeli: [1, 12], mobile: 1234, unique: unicode}]

step 2 : after add new item2 in the list2(item [66, 77]])
---print list2 ---- > [{nameMarket: name, listCodeMeli: [66, 77], mobile: 1234, unique: unicode},{nameMarket: name, listCodeMeli: [66, 77], mobile: 1234, unique: unicode}]

when the function
tt()
I disable it, everything works fine and the first list is placed in the second list with a new model, and the rest of the models in the second list do not change.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: TextWidget()
    );
  }
}

class TextWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<TextWidget> createState() => _TextWidgetState();
}

class _TextWidgetState extends State<TextWidget> {
  List<String> _list1 = [];
  late List<ModelFormatMarket> _list2;
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _list2 = [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: 400,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    //<<---------add to list1
                    onPressed: () {
                      _list1.add(_controller.text);
                      print(_list1);
                    },
                    child: Text('add to list 1'),)
              ],
            ),
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                      //-------> create model and add to list2
                     
                      onPressed: () {
                        onTapBtnOk();
                      },
                      child: Text( 'add to list2'),),
                  ElevatedButton(
                      //----------->>> list1 clear
                      onPressed: () {
                        _list1.clear();
                      },
                      child: Text('del'),)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List> tt() async {
    List<String> allCodeMeli = [];
    for (var element in _list2) {
      allCodeMeli.addAll(element.listCodeMeli);
    }
    return allCodeMeli;
  }

  onTapBtnOk() async {
    //------> check item list 2 in the all items list2

    // for (var element in _list2) {

    // }
    List list0 = await tt();

    // List list =
    //     allCodeMeli.where((element) => _list1.contains(element)).toList();
    // _list2.add(ModelFormatMarket(
    //     nameMarket: randomAlpha(2),
    //     unique: randomAlpha(4),
    //     listCodeMeli: _list1,
    //     mobile: 1234));
    for(var e in _list2){
      print(e.toMap()) ;
    }
   
    if (1 + 1 == 2) {
      _list2.add(ModelFormatMarket(
          nameMarket: 'name',
          unique: 'unicode',
          listCodeMeli: _list1,
          mobile: 1234));
         for(var e in _list2){
      print('==> ${e.toMap()}') ;
    }
    } else {
      print('codemeli exist in the list model');
    }
  }
}


class EntitiFormatMarket {
  final String unique;
  final String nameMarket;
  final List<String> listCodeMeli;
  final int mobile;
  const EntitiFormatMarket({
    required this.unique,
    required this.nameMarket,
    required this.listCodeMeli,
    required this.mobile,
  });

  @override
  bool get stringify => true;


}

class ModelFormatMarket extends EntitiFormatMarket {
  const ModelFormatMarket(
      {required super.nameMarket,
      required super.unique,
      required super.listCodeMeli,
      required super.mobile});

  ModelFormatMarket copyWith(
      {String? nameMarket,
      List<String>? listCodeMeli,
      int? mobile,
      String? unique}) {
    return ModelFormatMarket(
      unique: unique ?? this.unique,
      nameMarket: nameMarket ?? this.nameMarket,
      listCodeMeli: listCodeMeli ?? this.listCodeMeli,
      mobile: mobile ?? this.mobile,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'nameMarket': nameMarket,
      'listCodeMeli': listCodeMeli,
      'mobile': mobile,
      'unique': unique
    };
  }

  factory ModelFormatMarket.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ModelFormatMarket(
      unique: map['unique'] as String,
      nameMarket: map['nameMarket'] as String,
      listCodeMeli: List<String>.from(map['listCodeMeli'] as List),
      mobile: map['mobile'] as int,
    );
  }

  
}
```

Comment: you can do a simple test to catch the problem, 
add a simple print statement at the beginning of the build function, and please check if it is called when you tap on the button responsible for adding  new items to list..

Comment: Yes, I added, it is interesting that when the add function to list 2 starts, it adds the model to the list before starting the first line that should start the condition, it is interesting that it changes all the values in the list to the same value and the list is complete The models in list 2 will change to the new value

Comment: There could be a problem with ModelFormatMarket, do you use factory constructor?

Comment: all check , not problem in the model and factory constructor